# Как вставить переменную vue.js в css или scss?

Tags: vue.js

В коде представлен один из способов, как я меняю переменную цвета `new_color`, которая приходит с сервера, но такой способ мне не очень подходит, так как кода слишком много и везде вставлять `:style`, я думаю, как-то неправильно. Есть ли способ лучше, чтобы можно было менять одну, в моем случае - scss переменную `$main-color`, которая отвечает за множество стилей? Как-то я могу воздействовать на переменную `$main-color` из js кода или придется писать везде `:style`?

```
        <div class="container new_color" :style="background-color: new_color;">
        
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
   
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                new_color: '#00C851',
            }
        },
    }

</script>

<style lang="scss">

    $main-color: #df0000;

    .new-btn {
        border: 1px solid $main-color;
    }

    .new-btn2:hover {
        background-color: $main-color;
    }

       ............
        ...............
          ...................
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться возможностями обычных css переменных. Например:
Создадим переменную для цвета

```
:root {
  --color: red;
}
```

После чего из js мы сможем получить к ней доступ через

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--color')
```

Или

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--color')
```

Ну и естественно можно изменять её значение на необходимое

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--color', 'green')
```

Таким образом мы переопределим глобальную css переменную. Остальное уже дело техники, просто подставить вместо `green` свой цвет, который приходит с сервера.

Или если нужно назначить это значение вашей scss-переменной `$main-color`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это подойдет:

```js
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        style: 'bigRed'  
      },
      computed: {
          cssVars() {
              switch (this.style) {
                case 'bigRed':
                  return ({
                    '--text-color': 'white',
                    '--bg-color':  'red',
                    '--height': 50 + 'px'
                  })
                default:  
                  return {
                    '--bg-color':  'white',
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      methods:{
        change_style: function(){
          this.style = this.style === 'bigRed' ? '' : 'bigRed';
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
  button {
    color: var(--text-color);
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    height: var(--height);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="change_style" :style="cssVars">Нажми меня!</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```